# How do I update a RecordType's Name or IsActive status in Apex?

Tags: apex, metadata, record-type

I currently have RecordTypes for a particular object (Obj__c) in a production org.  I'm effectively trying to eliminate these as RecordTypes and planning a migration of that data into a picklist (Obj__c.Type__c).

The basic script migration script is an easy batch script:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Obj__c> objects) {
  for (Obj__c obj : objects) {
    obj.Type__c = mapRecordTypeToPicklist(obj.RecordType.Name);
  }
  update objects;
}
```

I'd like to make this a relatively easy deployment using Ant. However, I have the following challenges:

1. If I start by deploying my metadata changes (that is, making all Record Types inactive), I can no longer access `obj.RecordTypeId`.
2. I cannot use DML on a `RecordType` object and the `Schema.RecordTypeInfo` class does not expose any setters.
3. If I make all but one record type inactive and remove all profile  permissions on that record type, I can still access `obj.RecordTypeId`, but I don't know if it's possible to mark that record type as `isActive = false` in Apex, or if it has to be a manual process.

Is it possible to do this without either manually clicking to deactivate the record type once my batch script has completed, or making a second deployment once my batch script has completed?

Note - I'd like to do this without installing the bear-sized [apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) or any other package.